# Need to group only specific rows in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please consider the following simplified MySQL table:

```
id  | docID  | docTypeID | makeID | desc
1   | 1      | 1         | 1      | doc 1
2   | 1      | 1         | 2      | doc 2
3   | 2      | 2         | 1      | doc 3
4   | 3      | 3         | 2      | doc 4
5   | 1      | 1         | 4      | doc 5
6   | 2      | 2         | 5      | doc 6
7   | 4      | 1         | 1      | doc 7
```

In this example docID, docTypeID, and makeID are all foreign keys.

When a doc of docTypeID 1 is associated with multiple makes, I need to group those docs together and return a special make description ('multiple makes found').

What I need to return for this example table would be:

```
id  | docID  | docTypeID | makeID                | desc
1   | 1      | 1         | multiple makes found  | doc 1
3   | 2      | 2         | 1                     | doc 3
4   | 3      | 3         | 2                     | doc 4
6   | 2      | 2         | 5                     | doc 6
7   | 4      | 1         | 1                     | doc 7
```

Note that in the case of id 7, only a single make is found so there is no grouping performed.

I'm not sure how to limit grouping based on criteria or if that is even possible. I'm hopeful one of the SQL geniuses here can assist. Please let me know if any additional info is required. Thanks.

Comment: Show us what [you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How did you decide to return `id=1` rather than `2` or `5`?

Comment: only for doctype = 1? id 3 and id 6 have the same doctype but different makeid. why do u want both in that case?

Comment: @eggyal: It should return the min(id) when grouping.

Comment: @nawful: doctype 1 is the only time they should be grouped. Since 3 and 6 are doctype 2, they are excluded from the grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id,
       docID,
       docTypeID,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1
            THEN 'multiple makes found'
            ELSE MIN(makeID)
        END AS makeID,
       MIN(desc) AS desc
  FROM simplified_mysql_table
 GROUP
    BY docID,
       docTypeID
       CASE WHEN docTypeID = 1
            THEN 0
            ELSE id
        END
;
```

(N.B. The `MIN(id)` and `MIN(desc)` may not come from the same underlying record. If that's a problem, then you'll need to tweak the above a bit.)

Answer (score 3):

A simple group by, like:

```
select min(id),docID,docTypeID,
  case when count(1) > 1 then 'multiple makes found' else min(makeID) end AS makeID, 
  min(`desc`) 
 from docs_table group by docID,docTypeID;
```

should do it. Assuming `doc 6` and `doc 3` are in the same case.
Validated with [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d1be/10).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, I know about that, but in his case not sure if it matters, anyway see my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, in that case `min(id)` and `min(desc)` may relate to different records (which may or may not matter: it's unclear what are the OP's requirements).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Select id, DocId, DocTypeId, 
  Case MakeCount When 1 Then MakeId 
      Else 'multiple makes found' End MakeId, 
  Desc
From  (Select Min(id) Id, DocId, DocTypeId, 
            Count(Distinct MakeId) MakeCount, 
            Min(MakeId) MakeId, Min(desc) Desc
       From TableName
       Group By DocId, DocTypeId)
```

Comment: `Min(id)`, `Min(MakeId)` and `Min(desc)` could all relate to different records.