# group_concat performance issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I added a `group_concat` to a query and killed the performance. The explain plans are identical before and after I added it, so I'm confused as to how to optimize this.

Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
docID,
docTypeID,
CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1
     THEN group_concat( makeID )
     -- THEN 'multiple makes found'
     ELSE MIN(makeID)
END AS makeID,
MIN(desc) AS desc
FROM simplified_mysql_table,
(SELECT @curRow := 0) r
GROUP BY docID, docTypeID,
CASE WHEN docTypeID = 1
     THEN 0
     ELSE row_number
END;
```

Note the `CASE` statement in the `SELECT`. The `group_concat` kills performance. If I comment that line and just output 'multiple makes found' it executes very quickly. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I feel that the "row_number" elements can be removed. Can you provide sample data and output?

Comment: @ypercube . . . In MySQL, the row number variables are simply enumerating the output.  They do not have any effect on performance, since the engine only handles them during the final stage of returning results to the user.  However, it doesn't seem to be needed in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @Gordon: That's exactly what I was thinking (the use in `GROUP BY`). Besides that, the complicated GROUP BY suggests a not well normalized design. The query can probably be split into a UNION of two queries (one for `docTypeID = 1` and one for the rest).

Comment: @ypercube The sample data can be seen in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198298/need-to-group-only-specific-rows-in-a-query/13198483#comment17969497_13198483) question. The row_number becomes necessary in the real version of this query to give us a unique value to group on. When docTypeID = 1, we want to group up the records, otherwise don't. But I'm definitely open to other ideas.

Comment: Do you need the row_number in the results? Or is it needed only for the group by/

Comment: @ypercube It is not needed in the result. Just used for grouping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the original non-simplified version of this query we had a `DISTINCT`, which was completely unnecessary and causing the performance issue with group_concat. I'm not sure why it caused such a problem, but removing it fixed the performance issue.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, `group_concat` performance should not *kill* query performance.  It is additional work involving strings, so some slow down is expected.  But more like 10% rather than 10X.  Can you quantify the difference in the query times?

Question:  is MakeID a character string or integer?  I wonder if a conversion from integer to string might affect the performance.

Second, what would the performance be for `concat(min(MakeId), '-', max(MakedId))` isntead of the `group_concat`?

Third, does the real `group_concat` use `DISTINCT` or `ORDER BY`?  These could slow things down, especially in a memory limited environment.

Comment: The execution time goes from 2s to 250s when I add a `group_concat`.

Comment: MakeID is an integer. Switching to a concat does make the query run at the original 2s speed. The group_concat does not use a distinct or order by.

Comment: @Fook . . . Let me rephrase my first sentence then.  I am really surprised that `group_concat` would have such an impact on performance.  Are you working in a memory-limited environment?  Also, what is the maximum number of MakeIds in each group?  You might be able to restructure the query to get what you want.

Comment: Yes it really surprised us too. I believe the server has 8Gb mem. I don't think memory is an issue. The most grouped together is 4 makeIDs. We end up with the right data, just very slowly. Also, I tried adding an index on makeID but that didn't help either.

Comment: The alternative would be to enumerate the values in each group and then do a pivot.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to split the query into two parts, one for `WHEN docTypeID = 1` and one for the rest.

Try adding an index on `(docTypeID, docID, makeID, desc)` first:

```
SELECT 
    docID,
    docTypeID,
    CAST(makeID AS CHAR) AS makeID,
    `desc`
FROM 
    simplified_mysql_table,
WHERE 
    NOT docTypeID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    docID,
    1,
    GROUP_CONCAT( makeID ),
    `desc`                        -- this is not standard SQL
FROM 
    simplified_mysql_table,
WHERE 
    docTypeID = 1
GROUP BY 
    docTypeID,
    docID ;
```