# How to get multiple values in single column when using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query is

```
SELECT SUM(error_count) as error_count, job_id, operator_name
from table_name
GROUP BY operator_name
```

And the output is

```
error_count job_id operator_name    
17           12321     A.kumar
11           2212      Bindu
45           3412      Harish Babu
```

This is coming correctly for error count, but job id which is coming as the last job_id is not correct. I want all the job_id in comma seperated

```
SELECT SUM(error_count) as error_count , job_id = some_func(""+job_id), operator_name
from table_name
GROUP BY operator_name
```

So I can get the answer as

```
error_count   job_id         operator_name  
    17           12321,123     A.kumar
    11           2212 ,111     Bindu
    45           3412,3412     Harish Babu
```

I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, may work;)

```
SELECT SUM(error_count) as error_count , group_concat(job_id) as job_id, operator_name    
FROM table_name
GROUP BY operator_name
```

Also, take a look of [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Function Descriptions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks it does work ,,, i have some 100000+ records so does this group_concat affect speed

Comment: shud i use do both sum and group outside sql

Comment: What do you mean of outside sql, is that in `java` or `php` or other?

Comment: About performance, please check this [group_concat performance issue in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631499/group-concat-performance-issue-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Try Group_Concat,

```
    SELECT 
            SUM(error_count) AS error_count , 
            GROUP_CONCAT(job_id) AS jobids,
            operator_name 
    FROM
            table_name 
    GROUP BY 
            operator_name
```